# how to date1 and 15 of each month on mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table named `request` that user submit their requests, i will like to get info of all request from first 15 days of the current month and after the 15 days are done the rest of the same month and so an for every month when i'm on the current month.

```
SELECT * 
FROM request
WHERE req_date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 15 DAY
AND req_date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())- 1 DAY;
```

this is why I found for pass weeks but is based on current date and I need it to be based on the 1 of the month and 15 of the same month so I can know what happened in the month divided in 2 periods

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Example data and expected output could help us better understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for the first 15

```
SELECT * FROM request 
WHERE
req_date between  CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)   
        and  CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-15') as DATE)
;
```

and this for the second half month

```
SELECT * FROM request 
WHERE
req_date between  CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-16') as DATE)   
        and LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
;
```